# Compiler behaves differently on type of crate

Tags: rust

I have the following rust module.

`test.rs`:

```rust
pub fn foo(xs: &[f32]) -> Vec<f32> {
    xs.iter()
        .flat_map(|x| xs.iter().map(|y| *x - y))
        .collect()
}
```

If I compile this module (as *rlib*) I got an error:

```bash
$ rustc -o test.s --crate-type rlib test.rs

error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `x`, which is owned by the current function
[...]
```

The same can be as well experimented by using [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/T93Gx3drs) (which does pretty much the same thing).

---

However, if I compile the same function within a binary crate. The compiler accepts this code.

For example, by using [rust-playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b8c237885a18f1a5bf6ee6606b7f6d48).

(Note we are using the same compiler version here; that is, 1.63.0)

---

#### Question

Why compiler behaves differently in those two cases?

I suspect linker might kick in here, but I would like to have more technical confirmation.

Comment: Maybe the borrow checker get smarter recently ordinary you should do `move |y| *x - y)`. Previous not code that wasn't compiled is allowed to compiler if it's safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has nothing to do with crate types and everything to do with editions. Edition 2021 improved the borrow checker around closures.

In the Rust Playground, if you click the triple-dot menu to the right of the build profile and toolchain buttons, and select the 2018 edition, the error re-appears: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f8bb0c7ad9000ad9a9d4540351c74721

`rustc` likely defaults to the oldest edition of Rust (2015) for backwards compatibility. Godbolt does the same, since it just runs `rustc`. Rust Playground uses the latest edition.